# How to allow arrow keys in read command

Tags: bash

I made a bash script to use sendmail to send emails. However, when it asks for input, whenever I try to use the arrow keys to correct a typo, instead of moving the cursor, it just adds `^[[D` to the end. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `-e` option to `read`. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read):

> `-e`
>   Readline (see [Command Line Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing)) is used to obtain the line. Readline uses the current (or default, if line editing was not previously active) editing settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want. I searched a long time and did not find example until now so I am not sure this is the best method.

Then you can use arrows to get the history of the shell and what you passt in the past or write in a read cmd.

```bash
echo "Give your TV video : " 
read -e -i "" filev # assign read input to $filev, "" is to avoid to write something, do not know why, this is different than read -p "Give your TV video" filev
echo $filev >> ~/.bash_history # write what was written or paste in history
history -a # actualize the sheel history with the ~/.bash_history to get the $filev available in the shell after
```